# Why I can't set width for nav tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have navigation in div size `col-md-4` , and I have 6 tabs, I can't to aline all tabs.

I can aline when I change font-size of text tabs, thats not good solution for me.

I tried to set width for each tabs, but not working.
How can I set width for some tabs to be small but second to be bigger.

Also i have padding when I hover on the end of navbar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gMZg.png

```
        <nav class="row">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="tab1"><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Name &nbsp &nbsp<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>Text Link </a> </li>
                <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Message </a> </li>
                <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-oil"></span>10 </a> </li>
                <li class="tab5"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span> </a> </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> </a> </li>
            </ul>



    </div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-tabs li .tab5{

    width:4%;
}
```

Comment: I was edit now my answer and write thats

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. The 5th tab *is* smaller than the others. Are you trying to reduce internal padding? Please create a demo that shows the problem. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, you have to do this:

```css
.nav-tabs li.tab5 {
    width: 4%;
}
```

The class `.tab5` is on the `li` tag, therefore you have to connect them.

[**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/q1kF0qqdaX)

**UPDATE**

If you want to fit all in one row, try playing with the padding, like this:

```
.nav>li>a {
    padding: 10px 3px;
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://www.bootply.com/RRaD6SGRy1)

Comment: ok but thats not my solution, i can't to set all tabs in one line, beacuse area is col-md-4